# Firebase Storage Security Rule checking request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*') denies upload

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I only want images to be uploaded to Firebase Storage to a particular location. So I put `request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*')` rule for write, and now the image isn't being uploaded. Everything worked before, so I know for sure that this line is causing permission denied error. But what's wrong with this? I am merely checking according to the documentation if the `contentType.matches('image/*')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
FIRStorageMetadata *metadata = [[FIRStorageMetadata alloc] init];
metadata.contentType = @"image/jpeg";
[ref putData:attachmentData metadata:metadata completion:^(FIRStorageMetadata *metadata, NSError *error) { ... }]
```

Turns out that I didn't put contentType as the metadata. Ha!